# get_coherence : C_V method gets an error but U_Mass works

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels, nmf

I'm using the following code to check the coherence value. The problem is code below works well when I change the coherence type into "u_mass", but if I want to compute "c_v", an Index error occure.

Previous text process:

```
# Remove Stopwords, Form Bigrams, Trigrams and Lemmatization
def process_words(texts, stop_words=stop_words, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
    texts = [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts]
    texts = [bigram_mod[doc] for doc in texts]
    texts = [trigram_mod[bigram_mod[doc]] for doc in texts]
    texts_out = []
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=['parser', 'ner'])
    for sent in texts:
        doc = nlp(" ".join(sent)) 
        texts_out.append([token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags])
    # remove stopwords once more after lemmatization
    texts_out = [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts_out]
    ## Remove numbers, but not words that contain numbers.
    texts_out = [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if not word.isdigit()] for doc in texts_out]   
    ## Remove words that are only one character.
    texts_out = [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if len(word) > 3] for doc in texts_out]
    return texts_out
data_ready = process_words(data_words)

# Create Dictionary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_ready)
#dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=10, no_above=0.2) #filter out tokens

# Create Corpus: Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in data_ready]
# View:the produced corpus shown above is a mapping of (word_id, word_frequency).
print(corpus[:1])
print('Number of unique tokens: %d' % len(id2word))
print('Number of documents: %d' % len(corpus))
```

The output is :

```
[[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]]
Number of unique tokens: 6558
Number of documents: 23141
```

Now I set a base model:

```
## set a base model
num_topics = 5
chunksize = 100 
passes = 10 
iterations = 100
eval_every = 1  


lda_model = LdaModel(corpus=corpus,id2word=id2word, chunksize=chunksize, \
                       alpha='auto', eta='auto', \
                       iterations=iterations, num_topics=num_topics, \
                       passes=passes, eval_every=eval_every)
```

The last step is where the problem occurs:

```
# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_ready, dictionary=id2word, coherence="c_v")
coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```

Here is the error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

If I change coherence into 'u_mass', however, the code ablove can compute successfully. I don't understand why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install gensim==4.1.0
```

It seems that downgrade solves everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Apparently the error described here persist in gensim 4.2.0. Downgrading to 4.1.0 worked well for me.